# How to display an sql date in order when using ORDER BY?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display the following dates in order from smallest to biggest.

They are stored this way.

```
02-12-15
02-11-13
12-20-12
12-12-12
05-12-17
```

This is the following code I use

```
"SELECT ledate FROM `points_bar` WHERE student_id = '$studentID' ORDER BY ledate ASC";
```

And this is what I want to transform it to.

```
02-11-13
12-20-12
12-12-12
02-12-15
05-12-17
```

Can someone please point out to me a possible solution or give me a little push?

Comment: Please, ... could you show us also php code?

Comment: Try this 
`SELECT ledate FROM `points_bar` WHERE student_id = '$studentID' ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`ledate`)`

Comment: Not sure why this has a PHP tag since it's strictly an SQL ordering question - if you want to order it in PHP after it comes back from the database that's a different story.  To better help get an answer here could you tell us what data type the `ledate` column is?  Is it a `varchar` or a proper `date` type?  Also, it would be helpful if you told us what SQL engine you are running (SQL Server?  MySQL?)

Comment: oh, sorry for replying sooner. I was able to fix the issue with the answer chayan provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates are not in mysql supported date format. It treat as varchar. Change the SQL as follows should work.

```
"SELECT ledate FROM `points_bar` WHERE student_id = '$studentID' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`ledate`, '%m-%d-%y') ASC";
```

See [STR_TO_DATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

just cast ledate as date......

```
 SELECT ledate FROM `points_bar` 
 WHERE student_id = '$studentID' 
 ORDER BY cast(ledate as date) ASC
```